# Having updated master, how do i update a branch

Tags: git, github

I have a git repo(master branch)  and one other branch (x) .I recently have been updating the `x` branch and now on github i am getting this message on github  `x` branch `This branch is 22 commits ahead and 3 commits behind master`

Today i updated the master branch and i would now like the master branch and the `x` branch to be at the same level.What action should i take that will not mess up my repo?.

Comment: Don't miss my warning about rebasing shared branches!

Comment: I ran into that problem 44secs ago and i fixed it.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options, you can either merge `master` and `x` together, or you can rebase `x` onto `master`. These two options will both result in the same final state for your working tree, but the merge option will produce a merge commit in your case, while rebase will maintain a linear history.

A warning about rebase, however: if you're sharing your branch with other people, don't rebase (unless you know how to fix everyone else's branches when you do). Rebase rewrites history, which will cause sync problems with other people sharing your branch, unless they know how to recover from a rebase.

To merge:

```
git checkout x
git merge master
git checkout master
git merge x
git push origin master x
```

Or, to rebase:

```
git rebase master x
git checkout master
git merge x
git push origin master x
```